# Copy a discontinued app from one phone to another

Tags: apps, store, transfer

My family uses Life360 to keep track of each other's location, on a mixture of iOS and Windows Phone 8.1 phones.

We're adding a new Windows Phone 8.1 to the family, but I now discover that Life360 has been discontinued from the Windows Phone Store so I can't install it on the new phone.

It's still working fine on the phones that already have it installed... is there any way I can copy the application from a working phone to the new one?  It's a free app, so it's not like I'm trying to cheat the licensing.

(Note that the built-in "Share" feature won't work, because it just shares a link to the Store.)

(I'm a software developer, although for Windows desktop and web rather than Windows Phone.  A solution involving Visual Studio or whatever would be fine.)

Comment: You could try to login on the new phone with your own store account (an account which has already bought - even for free it is a 'buy-action' - the app). Then at least you should be able to see the app in the store at least. I'm not sure though whether it keeps working after switching back the microsoft account ...

Comment: malte, this works, post this as answer!

Comment: @malte: Thanks, but I don't think this will work in my case.  Even on my own phone, where the app is successfully installed, I can't see it in the Store.  If I go via Store / History then I can get to its Store page, but it says "This app is not available for your device."  Tapping for more information says "This might be because ... it was removed from the store by the publisher".  I don't think any solution involving the Store is going to work, I'm afraid

Comment: @RichieHindle Unfortunate. This might be because, before unlisting the application the developer changed the list of capable devices and excluded yours? Not sure if that is possible that way. But in general if you have bought an application you should still be able to install and use it after it has been discontinued / unlisted. So your last chance would be somehow getting the source code (maybe they opensourced it?) and building / installing through VisualStudio then :/

Comment: @malte: No such luck I'm afraid.  Unless there's some way to copy the binary from one phone to another, I think I'm stuck.  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. Even if you had the appx / xap file, the store would need to validate the app, which it can't since the app has been pulled.

I guess the only way would be to ask the developer if he would either republish the app or send you the source code / app package directly.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not going to be possible on windows phones as support is disabled from developer. You can sideload the app but there will be problems in using the App.
Alternative to Life360 is Guardian.It is nearly similar to Life360

Answer (score 0):

The [Life360](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/life360-family-locator/9wzdncrfj0gw?tduid=(34d07e1440466fd070f288b7483ecd66)(235158)(2804593)()()) app you are refering to has ended it's support for Windows phone on April 30,2016. So you cannot install it on a Windows 8.1 devices anymore.

Here is a word from developer regarding this,

> We are unable to support the latest version of Windows devices.
>   Life360 does not have any plans at this time to further develop the
>   app for the Windows mobile device platform. The current version of
>   Life360 is designed to work only on iPhone and Android smartphones.

You can find more information on the Windows central article [here](http://www.windowscentral.com/life360-ends-support-its-windows-phone-family-location-app).

---

However if you are running a Windows 10 mobile device it could be a different story(although I am not 100% sure). You can grab the appx file from [here](http://www.appx4fun.com/apps/1249/). Then,

1. Change the settings to Sideload an app or unlock the developer mode.
2. Copy the appx file to the SDcard.
3. Open the file explorer and click on the appx file to install the app.